# How to test that a method is called when a block is given

Tags: ruby, rspec

I got the task to write rspec tests for the following simplified method in case a block is given. The case when no block is given is already tested.

```
def make_something(name_id)
  name = find_name_by_id(name_id)
  if block_given? and name
    yield(something)
    name.save
  end
  name
end
```

It's no problem to test if something got yielded, but I've got a problem to spec if name.save is beeing called. 
I would do it like this:

```
let!(:name) { create(:name) }
describe "when given a block" do
  #works
  it "yields something" do
    expect { |b| subject.make_something(name.id, &b)}.to yield_with_args(something)
  end 

  #1. try: doesn't work
  it "saves the name" do
    expect(name).to receive(:save)
    subject.make_something(name.id) {}
  end

  #2. try: also doesn't work
  it "saves the name" do
    expect(name).to receive(:save)
    subject.make_something(name.id) {|b|}
  end
end
```

I'm shure the solution is obvious but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
let!(:name) { create(:name) }

describe "when given a block" do
  before do
    allow(subject).to receive(:find_name_by_id).with(name.id).and_return(name)
    allow(name).to receive(:save).and_call_original
  end

  it "yields something" do
    expect { |b| 
      subject.make_something(name.id, &b)
    }.to yield_with_args(something)
  end 

  it "saves the name" do
    subject.make_something(name.id) {}
    expect(name).to have_received(:save)
  end
end
```

The key idea is to stub the `find_name_by_id` method to return the same `name` instance that was created by the `let!`. If you do not do that, your spec fails because you expect `save` to be called in one instance of `name`, but it is actually called on another instance.